# SQL Server 2000 distinguishes between decimal zero 0.00 and -.00 while ADO.NET does not

Tags: sql-server

We're using SQL Server Standard Edition 8.00.760 (SP3) on a Small Business Server 2003 platform.
While tracking down an inexplainable System.Data.DBConcurrencyException for a Strongly Typed DataSet, I discovered the following problem:

Given is this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Auszahlung](
    [auszahlungid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [spesenkonto] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
```

And this query for a row originally inserted with decimals calculated in .NET 2.0 using a Strongly Typed DataSet:

```
SELECT [auszahlungid], [spesenkonto]
FROM [Auszahlung] 
WHERE [auszahlungid] = 35
```

When run on a Sql Server Management Studio 2005 client, I get this result:

```
auszahlungid spesenkonto
------------ ---------------------------------------
35           0.00

(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)
```

But when run on the Query Analyzer on the Sql Server 2000, I get this negative zero:

```
auszahlungid spesenkonto  
------------ ------------ 
35           -.00

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Consequently, the queries

```
SELECT [auszahlungid], [spesenkonto] 
FROM [Auszahlung] 
WHERE [auszahlungid] = 35
AND [spesenkonto] = 0.00
```

and (inconsequently on the SQL 2000 Query Analyzer)

```
SELECT [auszahlungid], [spesenkonto]
FROM [Auszahlung] 
WHERE [auszahlungid] = 35
and spesenkonto = -.00
```

both yield 0 rows, and any row update using a .NET Strongly Typed DataSet will raise a System.Data.DBConcurrencyException because of the the optimistic concurrency restriction.

Questions:

Is this a known bug in MSSQL?

How can I make our system reliable again without sacrificing optimistic concurrency?

Comment: What does Select [auszahlungid], CAST([spesenkonto] as nvarchar(16))
FROM [Auszahlung] 
WHERE [auszahlungid] = 35; return?

Comment: 'CAST([spesenkonto] as nvarchar(16))' is a good idea, as it allows me to spot the corrupted decimal column using SQL Server Management Studio 2005 without mstsc.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/−0_(number) negative zero is defined in IEEE 754 for floating point numbers, and there "negative zero and positive zero compare equal under default (numerical) comparison" (unlike on SQL Server 2000). Microsoft confirms a similar problem for decimals as BUG #: 16672 (SQLBUG_65) for the ancient SQL Server 6.5 Standard Edition: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189390/en-us

Comment: Makes sense.  My gut feel was that it was either a data corruption in your DB or a Bug.  (I haven't been able to reproduce it).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, when working with SQL2000 driver interprets numeric as float...
Can you try the following workaround

```
SELECT [auszahlungid], [spesenkonto] 
FROM [Auszahlung] 
WHERE [auszahlungid] = 35
AND ABS([spesenkonto]) < 0.01
```

Comment: Of course 'AND ABS([spesenkonto]) < 0.01' works, but I won't manually "correct" the code generated by VisualStudio 2005 in the Strongly Typed DataSet for handling optimistic concurrency. This is the core of the problem: The code generated by the framework seems (in rare edge cases) to produce data that can't be handled by that very code.

Comment: For optimistic concurrency we usually have only one field that is usually have the same name ModificationDate and that is assigned to DateTime.Now in .NET for all updated records. We modify conditions for concurrency to be WHERE [primary_key] = @original_key AND ModificationDate = @original_ModificationDate and exclude all other fields from concurrency conditions. I don't like the ideas to have autogenerated quesries with 20 or 30 fields in WHERE condition.